# JPA Recursive LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, jpql, recursive-query

I have an Entity called `Status` which (among other things) has a many-to-many relationship to itself representing the "Possible Next Statuses".

The idea is to be able to create a 'map' of transitions between statuses.

Now, I'm trying to produce a list of Statuses that aren't already linked to a given Status to populate a combo box in the "link to this Status" form (in other words, I want those statuses that COULD be linked).

So far, I've found 25 ways NOT to do this. :)

Ok, so a lot of people are asking for more details - I thought some things are taken for granted in terms of reasonable database design (and they don't actually matter for the answer).

a) All statuses have one and only one KEY column, their Primary Key.

b) Statuses are 'connected' to one another by means of a join table, which has 2 foreign keys, both being the primary key of a status.

c) If I have statuses A, B, C, and D - and I've already 'linked' statuses B and C to A so I have:  A -> B and A -> C the purpose is to find those Statuses existing in Status table, that aren't yet connected to 'A'. When I say 'A' I mean a status given as a parameter. So, if I was looking at Status A, I want all those not connected to 'A'. If I was looking at Status C I would want all those not connected to status C regardless if they are connected to a different status.

Any help would be appreciated. 
I am not looking for an exact query word by word, I am looking for 'the way it can be done'. I'll easily figure out how to apply the principle on my particular DB design, but I was unable to find the 'principle' to apply.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without better understanding the design. For example, I'm not sure why you need a recursive LEFT OUTER JOIN. Another example, I'm not sure why if your status has a field that represents a link to itself why you wouldn't just need to query for all status whose link field is null to gather all unlinked statuses. But that is probably cuz I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't have a field that links to itself - it's a **MANY TO MANY** relationship, so a separate Join table is used to match pairs.

Comment: Can you post your schema? You basically have a schema table with a surrogate key and another relationship table that has two fields that are FKEYs to the status table PKEY? And you simply want to query for all rows in Status that don't have a row in the relation table? You'll get better answers if you don't assume we are in your head and give us more detail. Maybe post the entities or the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select notLinkedStatus from Status notLinkedStatus
where notLinkedStatus.id not in
    (select linkedStatus.id from Status status
     inner join status.linkedStatuses linkedStatus
     where status.id = :theStatusId)
```